# ¿Cual seria la forma correcta de realizar las operciones con Bigdecimal?

Tags: java

Realmente quiero pasar todos estos Doubles a BigDecimal, quiero que mis valores sean mucho mas precisos y la información que he encontrado al respecto no me ha dejado muy bien claro como hacerlo. Le pido muy amablemente a alguien me ayude con esto.

```
//----------------------------------------------------
            int cant = Integer.parseInt(txtCantidadVenta.getText());
            double precio = Double.parseDouble(txtPrecioVenta.getText());
            double subtotal = cant * precio;                
            double IVA19 = subtotal * 0.19;
            double desc = Double.parseDouble(txtDescuento.getText());
            double ValorDesc = (subtotal * desc / 100);
            double TotalApagar = subtotal - ValorDesc + IVA19;
            //----------------------------------------------------
            txtTotalA.setText(""+TotalApagar);
            txtIVA.setText(""+IVA19);
            txtSubTota.setText(""+subtotal);
            txtValorDesc.setText(""+ValorDesc);
```

Quiero que mis operaciones se puedan realizar con ese dato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los objetos de tipo `BigDecimal` son inmutables, lo que significa que una vez los crees, no puedes cambiar su valor. Esto al comienzo puede generar algo de confusion acerca de como usar dichos objetos, pero es una [propiedad muy valiosa](https://www.genbeta.com/desarrollo/entendiendo-la-inmutabilidad-que-es-para-que-sirve-y-como-usarla).

Esta clase te ofrece diferentes tipos de operaciones en su [API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) para realizar las operaciones matematicas que tienes en tu código de ejemplo.

A manera de guía, las primeras lineas las podrias cambiar por algo similar a esto:

```
// en este caso usamos el constructor de BigDecimal que transforma un
// String en un objeto tipo BigDecimal
BigDecimal cant = new BigDecimal(txtCantidadVenta.getText());
BigDecimal precio = new BigDecimal(txtPrecioVenta.getText());

// una vez tenemos objetos tipo BigDecimal podemos realizar operaciones
// entre ellos, por ejemplo usando el metodo `multiply`
BigDecimal subtotal = cant.multiply(precio);

BigDecimal porcentajeIva = new BigDecimal("0.19");
BigDecimal iva = subtotal.multiply(porcentajeIva);
```

Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: González Vaya detalle si me dió más orientación, ya puedo hacer mis operaciónes.